# Where should I store my JWT token and what does httpOnly mean for a cookie?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth, urql

I read documentation about auth.
I work on Nuxt project and my server returns a cookie `HtppOnly`

*My questions :*

A lot of confusion about the storing of the JWT token, some do not recommend using the `localStroage`
I also read we can copy the token directly in the header for the next requests, but I don't find examples.
Also when a cookie is `HttpOnly`, how we can use it because is not accessible for JavaScript ?

```js
// https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/tree/main/exchanges/auth#quick-start-guide
if (result.data?.refreshLogin) {
  // save the new tokens in storage for next restart
  localStorage.setItem('token', result.data.refreshLogin.token);
  localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', result.data.refreshLogin.refreshToken);
  //...
}
```

*Ressources :*

- nuxt/auth => https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/auth-next
- urql/auth => https://www.npmjs.com/package/@urql/exchange-auth
- https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/authentication/
- https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/auth-exchange/#options
- https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/tree/main/exchanges/auth#quick-start-guide
- https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/
- https://www.howtographql.com/react-urql/5-authentication/

Comment: I don't know yet, I look for how build from scratch my authentification system. I can't use @nuxtjs/auth because it works with Axios, I use @Urql.

Comment: Your question was not really related to axios but a broad questioning so far. Looks very Apollo-y to me. ^^

Answer (score 1):

It is more safe to use cookies for JWT, rather than localStorage. And a short expiration time for the `accessToken` that you'd refresh with the `refreshToken`, often.

Here is a perfect explanation of the effect of `httpOnly`: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kLbCCAU/is-there-a-way-to-read-browser-cookie-with-httponly-flag-set-on-ibpm-856-cf02-

> An HttpOnly cookie cannot be accessed by client-side APIs, such as JavaScript. This restriction eliminates the threat of cookie theft via cross-site scripting (XSS).
> If the browser allowed you to access it then it would be a defect in the browser.

> You could remove the HTTPOnly flag if there is a particular cookie you want modified by the browser and are not worried about XSS for it. Only the server side code should have access to these cookies.

---

If you expect your cookie to be modified by your client code, you may only set `secure: true` and allow for it to be used for more that `httpOnly`.

[cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) is great for managing client-side cookies.

---

##### Answering to your comments:

What middleware are you talking about?

Is your thing working with something like Insomnia? Send the GQL call and see if you have something or not.

---

I've only worked with GQL on client side so I'd give my feedback on where it should be but it may be not 100% accurate.

1. You should have some backend logic to handle for the whole login flow but if you want to manage the fact that somebody is logged-in or not, this will indeed be on the frontend. You will need some state to see what to display to the end user. Of course, this relies on the assumption that your are running your app as an SPA only and that your backend serves as a GQL API. But you may have various ways of tackling this depending of the amount of privacy of your pages and so on. Hard to give an answer to that kind of a broad answer.
2. Both backend do handle JWT. The client is responsible to store it and check if it's expired, then refresh it. It sends it to the backend to see if you can have access to the requested data and so on. For the frontend, if you want to keep it in your cookies to persist between refreshs, well it's on the frontend.
3. JWT refresh token is stored on the frontend. When it is expired, your frontend should send it to your backend for it to update it's value. Then, you can keep an updated version until it expires again.
4. If by resource requests, you mean accessing the values contained into your databases, this is some backend job. Your frontend is responsible of calling queries/mutation without even knowing what is behind the curtain. This is the whole point of GQL, make the frontend like more friendly by removing all the possible endpoints that a typical REST API do have.

---

##### To sum up

Your frontend cannot contain sensitive information, this is the main thing to get here.

Most of your question are knowing which side of the stack is concerned. I'm not sure if you are a fullstack developer but you should probably read some articles on how GQL works in general.

Also, there are **a lot** of questions here. I do recommend trying to focus on only one thing at a time and not go in to many ways at the same time otherwise it will be hard to understand as a whole.

Moreover, those kind of posts on StackOverflow (asking to many things) will be closed in no time.

Comment: I don't succeed, I do the requests from client side directly to graphQL API and middleware of Nuxt is not triggered. I don't understand how handle authentification with a SSR server.1) The login/logout request must be called from client or server side of Nuxt ?
2) Who receipt and handle JWT cookies, client or server side ?
3) Who refresh JWT, server or client side ?
4) The resources requests must be calle from client or server ?