# Refresh token is better to receive in JSON or immediately set it to cookie?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, authorization, nuxt.js

I am building Token-Based Authentication using Nuxtjs/auth. When I login the user I get this response from the server:

```
JSONResponse({
 'result': True,
 'token_type': 'bearer',
 'access_token': *****,})/n
:cookie(key="refresh_token", httponly=True)
```

I am wondering what is the difference from security point of view if it would be like that:

```
JSONResponse({
 'result': True,
 'token_type': 'bearer',
 'access_token': *****,
 'refresh_token': *****,})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I store my JWT token and what does httpOnly mean for a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879764/where-should-i-store-my-jwt-token-and-what-does-httponly-mean-for-a-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

A `httpOnly` cookie is safer, but the payload itself will not add anything regarding security.