# Laravel 9 SPA athentication with nuxt, is saving tokens and sessions in cookies safe?

Tags: laravel, authentication, cookies, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So I am making a web app with nuxt 3 and laravel, and I cant seem to get the [SPA authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) to work. So I am for now generating a usertoken and saving it in the cookies, so my user keeps logged in. But I am doubting that this is a safe way to keep my user authenticated and do other actions. I tried looking up whether it is good to store it in cookies. But there are to many mixed reviews on this subject.

(the reason why I personally storing it in the cookies, is because nuxt3 is `ssr` and I wont be able to get the token if it was stored in the localstorage)

I know that cookies are more venerable to `xsrf` attacks and localstorage to `xss` attacks.

But what I understand when I am going to use the SPA authentication of laravel, those sessions and tokens are going to be saved in the cookies as well right? So what difference does that make with saving a token in the cookies?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: store it in the cookies + add some flags to it.

---

Here is [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67879799/8816585), `HTTPOnly` and [with `Secure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) adds a layer of security to it.
And that one should probably be totally fine.

XSRF is something that should not happen on your website but if somebody got caught by phishing, you can't really protect the website more than that.
The security realm is a big thing, a system will never be bullet-proof: it's more of a matter of following the best practices as much as possible.

You can mitigate the damages but assigning a short TTL to your tokens and checking their viability on a middleware that runs on every client-side navigation.

---

I'm not an expert in security but you will probably not need one either. Follow that advice and consider your job done.
Social engineering + other breaches can lead to your website being breached in far easier ways.

If you are a big corporate company that needs those drastic security measures, you also have probably spent millions on ways to lock your network security up.

Answer (score 0):

If your Laravel api(assuming you are using Laravel as API) and SPA(Nuxt) are on the same domain, You can use Sanctum cookie-based session authentication.

#1. Uncomment EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful middleware in  app/Http/Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
   \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

#2. Add SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in your .env file

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```

#3. In config/cors.php, change support credentials to true

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

#4. Before you hit login endpoint make request to 'sanctum/csrf-cookie' and then POST request to login endpoint

```
// Sanctum endpoint to generate cookie
    Route::get('sanctum/csrf-cookie', function () {
        return response('OK', 204);
    });

    Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::post('auth/login', 'login');
    });
```

#5. Enable the 'withCredentials' option on your application's global axios instance

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: Axios doesn't work anymore in nuxt 3. But thank you in advance

Comment: use fetch and pass headers, make sure to have the credentials include to allow sending user credentials
    await $fetch(config.baseURL + '/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token,
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            body: {
              "email": email,
              "password": password
            }
          })

Comment: Any ideas on how to implement token-based authentication instead of cookie-session? I want to use Laravel sanctum & Nuxt3. I know I have to attach token to authorization headers, but if a user manually refreshes the browser the token is lost from there.